# Retrieving data from front end to oracle DB in python

Tags: python, oracle

i m new to python. i want to store some data about files (file name, last modified date, file size, file directory, etc) from web URL to back end (oracle DB).

please help me with code structure

Comment: what have you tried? 

Receiving data from front-end sounds like you're expecting data in a view function in your backend. 

This article would quickly get you up and running with [oracle db in python](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-and-oracle-database-c7b5d4d7fa4c)

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statements you are using in the database; **YOUR** attempt at solving the problem in Python (whether its via `cx_oracle`, Django, SQLAlchemy or something else); the errors you are getting with **YOUR** solution; what the expected output is. StackOverflow is not a site for tutorial or to write your code for you; it is for help debugging so you will need to put the effort in first to attempt a solution before we can help you to finish getting it working.

Comment: Putting aside for a moment the general question ("how do I store this information in my database") and looking at a couple of specifics ... Exactly _why_ would you store a file's last modified date and size?  These are things that could (and probably will) change after you have captured it, rendering the information you have captured invalid.

Comment: In case you haven't come across it, the Oracle Python cx_Oracle documentation is [here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Also there are examples [here](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples).  You will find these useful.